# Difference in time measured by clock and steady_clock

Tags: c++11, clock, c++-chrono

I was trying to measure the time taken to execute a specific function in my code. Initially I used the `clock()` function as below

```
clock_t start = clock();
do_something();
clock_t end = clock();

printf("Time taken: %f ms\n", ((double) end - start)*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Later I was reading about the `chrono` library in `C++11` and tried to measure the same with a `std::chrono::steady_clock` as below

```
using namespace std::chrono;

auto start = steady_clock::now();
do_something();
auto end = steady_clock::now();
printf("Time taken: %lld ms\n", duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count());
```

The time measured by the first code snippet (using `clock`) was `89.53 ms` and that measured by `steady_clock` was `1140 ms`.

Why is there such a big difference in time measured by both the clocks?

Comment: If possible, could you create a [mcve] please?

Comment: @Rakete1111: Here is the [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f74e57079978629) to a small test case where the issue is reproducible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`clock` measures processor time, whereas `steady_clock` measures physical time.  So you can get differences like this if `do_something()` was preempted by other processes (such as checking mail or whatever).

[Daniel H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27302/daniel-h) makes a great point below in the comments that this can also happen if `do_something()` isn't CPU bound.  For example if it sleeps, blocks on locking a mutex, waits on a condition variable, etc.

Comment: That would also show up id `do_something` isn’t CPU bound, right?

Comment: @DanielH:  Thanks Daniel, good point.  I've added your comment to my answer.

Comment: @HowardHinnant What would be the correct approach to measure time taken by a function that can sleep, blocks on a mutex etc?

Comment: @nangal.vivek:  There is no one right answer.  It depends on what you want to measure.  If you want to measure how long a function takes, use `steady_clock`.  If you want to measure how many CPU cycles are consumed by your function, use `clock`.  I find myself using `steady_clock` more often because I'm usually interested in the elapsed time a function takes.